# Stuck on EULA screen when installing netflix-desktop

Tags: apt, netflix

I am trying to install netflix-desktop on my laptop running 13.10. I followed the instructions here:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compolio  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install netflix-destop
```

After a while, there is a EULA in my xterm that says I must agree to it to get the software. At the bottom of the screen there is 'Ok'

I have hit <kbd>enter</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, typed 'OK' in that xterm but it never gets past that. The application is not available because if I try to launch netflix-desktop in another xterm, it doesn't know what I'm talking about and netflix isn't found on my system when I search search.

Can anybody tell me what I'm supposed to do next or what I should have done so that I'm not in this situation next time?

Comment: Please don't post your solution in your question, but post this as an answer instead. That is how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by OP:

> I found out that I had to hit the down arrow several times till the OK lit up. Then I could hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to go to the next step. Then by using the arrow keys to highlight the proper respose(s), I was able to complete the installation. I haven't actually brought up Netflix yet, but it appears to be installing things as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as OP, however TAB worked for me instead of arrows. Would have simply upvoted but not cool enough yet...